# Continuous function with domain IN

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T = \{\emptyset , \mathbb N\} \cup \{\{1,2, \dots,n\} | n \in \mathbb N\}$ be a topology for $\mathbb N$. How can I prove that if a function $f : (\mathbb N,T) \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, then it is constant.

Comment: That's just for one to know that they are the only open and closed sets of this topology!!

Comment: @RossMillikan: the OP is enumerating the open sets so $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb{N}$ need the braces. ($\emptyset \cup \Bbb{N} \cup \ldots$ would just be $\Bbb{N}$ without them.)

Comment: Oh ok, I understand it now. But my professor always defines topologies this way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: what are the closed sets in your topology $T$? The singleton sets $\{x\}$ in $\Bbb{R}$ are closed so, if $f$ is continuous $f^{-1}[\{x\}]$, must be closed.

Comment: I know but that is my problem. I don't know how to identify the inverse image of the singleton set!

Comment: Is it $\{n+1,...\}$?

Comment: Yes! That's what the closed sets look like.

Comment: Ok, then it is constant no matter what image we have

Comment: So the inverse images $f^{-1}[\{x\}]$ and $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ of any two points $x$ and $y$ in $\mathrm{ran}(f)$ have points in common, so ....

Answer (score 0):

For sake of completeness, we have, by using Rob's hint:

If $x,y \in \text{ran}(f)$, then by continuity of $f$ and the fact that singletons are closed in $\mathbb{R}$ (finite sets are closed in Hausdorff spaces):

$f^{-1}[\{x\}] = \{n + 1, n + 2, \dots\}$

$f^{-1}[\{y\}] = \{m + 1, m + 2, \dots\}$

Since the intersection of the two sets above is non-empty, we have that $x = y$, since $f$ is a function.

Also, as a nitpick, $0 \in \mathbb{N}$, so $0$ has to be included in the sets above, but the argument is the same.